# Test loading of image in Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I want to test Cypress that an image is loaded into the page.

My source code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className="image">
          <img src="../images/Banana-Snowboard.png" alt="Snow Board" />
        </div>
        <div className="middel aligned content">
          <div className="description">
            <a>Snow Board</a>
            <p>Cool Snow Board</p>
          </div>
          <div className="extra">
            <span>Submitted by:</span>
            <img
              className="ui avatar image"
              src="./images/avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my test is like this:

```
it("should display a image in element div with class image", () => {
  cy.get('div[class="image"]').find("img"); // some code that test that image is loaded so that it is displaye on the web page
});

it("shoul diplay a image in element div with class image inside class extra", () => {
  cy.get('div[class="extra"]').find('img[class="ui avatar image"]');
  //some code that check that image is loaded so that it is display the web page
});
```

How will that code look like?

Answer (score 54):

I have updated our recipe for static resource loading, see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/pull/363

To check if an image has finished loading, the simplest way is to check the image's `naturalWidth` or `naturalHeight` property.

```
// we can wait for the <img> element to appear
// but the image has not been loaded yet.
cy.get('[alt="delayed image"]')
.should('be.visible')
.and(($img) => {
  // "naturalWidth" and "naturalHeight" are set when the image loads
  expect($img[0].naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)
})
```

Alternatively, you can use performance entries to confirm that any static resource has finished loading, see the above pull request for the details.

Comment: Finally got round to trying this out, works great. Many thanks!

Comment: this does not work with Next.js Image comoponent https://i.imgur.com/5aXdrR7.png

Comment: @markokraljevic can you provide a small reproducible example to show it? I have been testing Nextjs Image just fine recently using naturalWidth (it was having min 1x1 pixel dimensions right away, so I picked min 100 pixels when checking), read https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/check-more-things/

Answer (score 8):

What you're looking for is assertions, and in this case, `should('be.visible')` seems like it would fit the bill. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html

```
it("should display a image in element div with class image", () => {
  cy.get('div[class="image"]').find("img").should('be.visible');
});
```

Comment: What is the exact Cypress behaviour? A 404 image is still a visible element on the page (especially with an alt attribute)

Comment: @SebastienC. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing.html#Functional-vs-visual-testing In theory, Cypress is not supposed to check if an image is broken, some other tools like Aplitools would do a better work

Answer (score 3):

I use this chain of cypress to wait for all images that should load for the user, and not more (excluding invisble or not initialized images):

Get all images (including in shadow dom - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Arguments)

```
cy.get('img', { includeShadowDom: true })
```

that have a src tag (css selector - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter)

```
.filter('[src]')
```

and are visible (jquery selector - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai-jQuery)

```
.filter(':visible')
```

and are all loaded ("naturalWidth" and "naturalHeight" are set when the image loads)

```
.should(($imgs) => $imgs.map((i, img) => expect(img.naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)));
```

All in one:

```
cy.get('img', { includeShadowDom: true })
        .filter('[src]')
        .filter(':visible')
        .should(($imgs) => $imgs.map((i, /** @type {HTMLImageElement} */ img) => expect(img.naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)));
```

Thanks to others posts here and at other places.

Comment: A small adjustment - use `[src]:not([src=""])` to handle the case where src is defined but has no value

Answer (score 1):

I like jehon's take. But in my case our team is not able to follow the best practice of having a dependable, static image set, so I don't want broken image urls to fail the test. This version of the code doesn't fail on missing images:

```
cy.get('img', { timeout: 10000, includeShadowDom: true })
  .filter(selector)
  .filter(':visible')
  .each((el) => {
    const url = el[0]?.src || el[0]?.srcset
    if (url)
      cy.request({ url: url, failOnStatusCode: false }).then((resp) => {
        if (resp.status == 200)
          cy.get(el).should((el) => {
            expect(el[0].naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)
          })
      })
  })
```

Comment: Small note `const url = el[0]?.src ? el[0]?.src : el[0]?.srcset` can be `const url = el[0]?.src || el[0]?.srcset`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by

```
    it('Test Broken Images', function() {
    cy.get('img').each(($img) => {
    cy.wrap($img).scrollIntoView().should('be.visible');
    expect($img[0].naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0);
    expect($img[0].naturalHeight).to.be.greaterThan(0);
    });
    })
```

Comment: Property 'naturalWidth' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'