# Why defaultTimeOut is not working when checking images if visible?

Tags: cypress

I need help on implementing the defaultTimeOut and I have this code:

```
  it('Check Image if visible', () => {
          //IMG
          cy.get('[class^="image1"]:nth-child(1) img').should('have.length', 5)
          .each(($el) => {
          expect($el).to.be.visible
          })
      });

it('Check Image 2 if visible', () => {
            //IMG
            cy.get('[class^="image2"]:nth-child(1) img').should('have.length', 5)
            .each(($el) => {
            expect($el).to.be.visible
            })
        });
```

But it checks the images in an instant it doesn't wait 4000ms  for the image to load and check if it's visible even if i set the `{timeout:10000}` in the element and `defaultTimeOut:10000` on config. as far as i want i don't want to use cy.wait. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test loading of image in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246606/test-loading-of-image-in-cypress)

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is the `<img>` element is there but the image content has not loaded.

Try

```js
cy.wrap($el)
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('have.prop', 'naturalWidth')
  .should('be.greaterThan', 0)
```